# How can I fit in a linear model with specifiy level of a factor in R?

Tags: r, categorical-data

`Stfmodel1<-lm(SATISFACTION~AGE+SEVERITY+ANXIETY+SURG,data=Stf)`
SURG is a factor variable with levels "Yes" and "No"
This is my code and I want to fit in a linear model with SURG = yes and SURG = NO separately, could anyone tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was probably more appropriate as a [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) question but I write the solution for you here. You can achieve what you want by the following codes:

```
Stfmodel1 <- lm(SATISFACTION~AGE+SEVERITY+ANXIETY, data=subset(Stf, SURG=="Yes"))
Stfmodel2 <- lm(SATISFACTION~AGE+SEVERITY+ANXIETY, data=subset(Stf, SURG=="No"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you accept the answer by clicking the tick sign on the left?